# Jekyll: How to make it not to create sub-folder for each page?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

My Jekyll root folder is like:

```
   site_root/
        |_______ tutorials/
                    |________ index.html
                    |________ tutorial1.md
```

however, after building, it generates a sub-folder for tutorial1.md as:

```
_site/
   |______ tutorials/
               |_______ index.html
               |________ tutorial1/
                             |_______ index.html
```

how can I make it not to generate the sub-folder but the plain page tutorial1.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Jekyll creates a folder structure of `/some-title/index.html` for a permalink style of (for example) `permalink: /:title`. To achieve a sane folder structure with friendly permalinks, install [jekyll-clean-urls](https://github.com/willnorris/jekyll-clean-urls) (which handles this specific case) or a similar plugin. That will produce a folder structure like this:

```
/some-title.html
```

Or for a permalink style of `/:categories/:title`:

```
/some-category/some-title.html
```

...getting rid of the wasteful folder structures. The basic plugin logic is straightforward. Example from [sources](https://github.com/willnorris/jekyll-clean-urls/blob/master/clean-urls.rb#L37):

```
def destination_with_clean_urls(dest)
  path = destination_without_clean_urls(dest)
  path.sub!(/\/index.html$/, '.html') if clean_urls?(permalink)
  path
end
```

You can then rely on MultiViews, mod_rewrite, or similar apparatus such that requests for `/some-title` or `/some-category/some-title` map to `some-title.html`. I'm using this myself in production (see profile website) and it's been solid thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Can be a `permalink: tutorial1/` in the page front matter. In this case remove it, or change it to `permalink: tutorial1.html`.

or

A 'permalink: pretty' set in `_config.yml`. In this case change to 'permalink: none'

Answer (score -1):

I believe it has to do with `relative_permalinks` in your `_config.yml`. Try inverting its value.

You did not specify Jekyll version. Check out:

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/